# How to override an array in my config file during test?

Tags: symfony, authentication, config

In dev and production, I use a PhpCas guard authenticator. During test, I want to **replace** it by another authenticator, a traditional login form authenticator.

So I have two config files. Here is the main `security.yaml` config file which works perfectly:

```yaml
security:
    # ...
    firewalls:
        # ...
        #Main firewall
        main:
            anonymous: true

            # We use Guard !
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    # This service is declared in services.yaml
                    # - app.security.login_form_authenticator
                    # CAS Server Cerbere
                    - phpcasguard.cas_authenticator
```

And I have a `security.yaml` in the `test` subdirectory which is perfectly loaded:

```yaml
security:
    firewalls:
        #Main firewall
        main:
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    # During test, I do not use CAS Server.
                    # This service is declared in services.yaml
                    - app.security.login_form_authenticator
```

But the `app.security.login_form_authenticator` is added. It **does not replace** `the phpcasguard.cas_authenticator`.

**How to override `guard.authenticator` array in my `test/security.yaml` file ?**

*(I tried to used the guard.entry_point configuration key, but the two guard authenticators are loaded, so after the first authentication, my functional test tried to connect on CAS server. It is only changing the priority.)*

*(I tried to use key like the example below, but it does not replace it)*

```
security:
    firewalls:
        #Main firewall
        main:
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    # During test, I do not use CAS Server.
                    # This service is declared in services.yaml
                    0: app.security.login_form_authenticator
# AND in the main security file I used                        
                    0: phpcasguard.cas_authenticator
```

Comment: You could just re-structure your config files to *only* load specific `security.yml` files in specific environments. Remove the general `security.yml` import from config.yml and add imports for `security_prod.yml` to `config_prod.yml`, an import for `security_test.yml` in `config_test.yml` and so on.

Comment: Yes, I think there is no other solution. I did it and it works.